# Geodjango Installation Error: the procedure could not be found

Tags: django, installation, geodjango, geos

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 280,
 in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", lin
e 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", l
ine 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", l
ine 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", l
ine 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 6,
 in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 4, in
 <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\forms.py", line 6, in
 <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 17, in
 <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 48, i
n <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 96, in __n
ew__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 264, in ad
d_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 124, in
 contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length(
))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 34, in __geta
ttr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 198, in __getite
m__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_bac
kend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\bas
e.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis.introspection import PostGISIntr
ospection
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\int
rospection.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import OGRGeomType
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line
 41, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5
, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as capi
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py",
 line 8, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import lgdal
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line
47, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 127] The specified procedure could not be found
```

I tried installing my app in another laptop but it throws an error in which I haven't encounter before. What causes it? Any help?

I followed the installation guide, installed all in 32-bit version. 
After running the geodjango.bat file from the [installation guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows) the above error occurs.

Error after running the command: `python manage.py runserver`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98274/osgeo4w-error-the-procedure-entry-point-ncsecw-dll)

> OSGEO4W has upgraded to GDAL 1.11, but QGIS 2.2 not; causing the version conflict. The dll should have the same date as the GDAL exe files.
>
> [...]
>
> If you don't need ECW support, you could simply delete or move the dll.